Degrees Apart Puzzle

There's an old blog post I stumbled upon that had a nice puzzle that I was trying to work through:
https://measuringshadowsblog.blogspot.com/2012/08/contest-number-two-two-degrees-of.html
As explained there, the rule is that each empty box needs to be filled in with a word with some fairly direct connection to the two already-filled-in words linked to it. The author included some hints (filled in some answers) on this followup post (spoilers obviously):
https://measuringshadowsblog.blogspot.com/2012/12/re-starting-blog-and-results-of-second.html
I've come to reason that:
Man, Piece ->

 King (piece in chess and a king is a man)

Problem, Jogging ->

 Exercise (sets of problems are exercises and jogging is a type of exercise)

President, Orange ->

 Agent (low credence on this one) (a president is an agent and agent as in agent orange)


I would say that President + Orange = Donald Trump. But this is from 2012.

Bishop is a man.

From this Reddit post with a half decent answer:

  Sherlocks/Winchesters: Detectives.

 Apple/Put Away: Store. The Apple store and to store something.

 Therefore Detectives + Store = Store Detectives or "Security"

 Man/Piece: Gun. Gunman and a gun is a "piece."

 Problem/Jogging: Exercise.

 Therefore Gun + Exercise = Drill (as in going to the shooting range as a military drill.)

 Security + Drill = Evacuation

On the other side:

 Christian/Bowie: Soldier (Sam Bowie at the Alamo and Onward Christian Soldiers)

 President/Orange: Aide (Presidental Aide and Orangeaide)

 Therefore: Soldier + Aide = V.A. (for Veterans Administration which provides aid to soldiers)

 Below we already have it solved to "Avis Express."

 Avis Express = Airport (because that is the only place I have ever seen an Avis Express)

 Therefore: VA + Airport = Richmond (although there are many other airports in Virginia)

 Because: Richmond + Evacuation = Fire, as the burning of Richmond after its evacuation during the civil war is a famous historical event.


Please can you include the relevant content here. As it stand this is a link-only answer and is likely to be deleted.
